# How to add listeners to JSF session initialization event?

Tags: jsf

I'm writing a webapp that can be accessed through several different JSP pages.
I'm using Session scope since I assume that there can be several different sessions active.

If I knew I had one entry to the app I would has probably used the constructor of that bean as an initialization indicator but each JSP page uses a different Bean so I'm not sure how get the Session Initialized Event.

Any JSF Session Listeners that can be defined in faces-config.xml that I missed?

Thanks!
(P.S - Working with JSF 1.2 Currently)

Comment: what's the final goal of this listener? I didn't very much get the question.

Comment: To catch an event upon starting new JSF session. I'm basically looking for a ServletContextListener for JSF Sessions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions are not a JSF concept. They are a general web concept. Hence the servlet-api gives you the [`HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). You should map it with `<listener>` in web.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for a HttpSessionListener. See this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/).